# <Interface> is already registered error in blend using MVVMLightV4

Tags: mvvm-light

I've been using MVVMLight for some time now and started using V4 since it was first made available.

However one issue has always persisted with me which I've been unable to solve.

If I create a project using the MVVM 4 project template the solution builds fine, runs fine and works ok in blend.

However

If I start my own project and install MVVMLight V4 using Nuget, as soon as I add even a basic DataService and enable the commented out code in the ViewModelLocator template and open up the project in Blend I just get an error:

"Class  is already registered"

Just trying to get to the bottom of this very annoying error.

Just to be clear it doesn't matter what is in the DataService as even with an interface and service with only 1 empty function gives the same error

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Blend, for some reason, may initialize the ViewModelLocator more than once.

So you need to add a check:

```
if (!SimpleIoc.Default.IsRegistered<ISomeService>())
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ISomeService, SomeService>();
```

Comment: That would be fine except it doesn't explain why EXACTLY the same code works differently between the New Project template for MVVMLight and Adding MVVMLight through Nuget.  But thanks for the work around for now

Comment: Thx trydis! The workaround works! I was going crazy with the same issue using Win8

Comment: @IvanFioravanti My pleasure. I was scratching my head for some time before i realized what was happening :)

Comment: Spot on! Full Marks! - Ibrar

Comment: Goddamn this saved me some time. This was the thing that stopped my dummy data from working.

Comment: Wow, that's 3 days of my life just gone. If I could upvote more than once I would. It also matches the symptoms exactly. Do a rebuild: problem goes away. Look at a xaml, so far so good. Click away click back: some refresh cycle tries to register again.